# Sharepoint 3.0 - hierarchical list

Tags: sharepoint

I have a very restricted user access to our Sharepoint site, I can create new pages, custom lists and so on but can't write code against it or even deploy web parts to it.
Any way I want to create a list based view which is hierarchical in nature and grouped so it looks something like this:

```
             Task item 1.0
Grp 1        Task item 1.1
             Task item 1.2

             Task item 2.0
Grp 2        Task item 2.1
             Task item 2.2
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the standard "Group By" feature on SharePoint views achieve what you need?